# Designated Initialiser on struct causes segfault in strcpy and realloc

Tags: c, struct, initialization, dynamic-memory-allocation, string-literals

I'm using `WSL Ubuntu-20.04 LTS` and compiling with `gcc`.

I'm preparing some examples to teach the basics of C to CS Students and as I was reading about designated Initialisers, the following bit of code caused errors,

```c
    typedef enum {male, female} sexe;

    struct human_t {
        char * name;
        char * title;
        sexe gender;
    };

    struct human_t steve = {.name = "Steve", 
                              .title = "Mr.", 
                              .gender = male
                             };

    strcpy(steve.name, "AA");
```

And reading the manual on `strcpy` the destination buffer being of larger size than `"AA"` I'm simply at a loss as to why this doesn't work.

I also observed the following :

```c
    struct human_t steve = {.name = "Steve", 
                              .title = "Mr.", 
                              .gender = male
                             };
    char * new_name = "Gobeldydukeryboo";
    realloc(steve.name, strlen(new_name));
    strcpy(steve.name, new_name);
```

And this returns the error `realloc(): invalid pointer`.

Reading the manual on `realloc` the pointer must have been returned by a `malloc` call for it to work.
I'm having a feeling that designated initialisation does not call `malloc`, which would explain why `realloc` fails, it doesn't, however, explain why `strcpy` fails.

What's going on here ?

Comment: What is `struct human_t`? Suspect it is a `char *` which means you are assigning a stirng literal to it and thus can't write to or realloc it. Please give complete code as a [mre].

Comment: Is the formal definition of a `struct human_t` left to our own vivid imaginations? The code suggests members like `name` and `title` are `char*`, and if so, you're first code is trying to blast over a read-only string literal. Further, unless otherwise previously set with a `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`, etc., or NULL, submitting a pointer to `realloc` invokes *undefined behavior*, thus explaining the second failure.

Comment: *the destination buffer being of larger size* The size is not the issue. I assume, `name` is a pointer `char*`. (Otherwise your call to `realloc` would not make any sense)  You do not have a buffer where you can write to. Your pointer points to a constant string literal. You need to provide an array for `name` or allocate dynamic memory.

Comment: Fwiw, the second code is basically entirely wrong at every step regardless. Not only is `steve.name` *not* dynamic, and therefore not permissible to `realloc`, you're not retaining the result of the `realloc` anyway (that function return result is important, and you're ignoring it), and the size is wrong (one char short due to not accounting for the terminating nullchar).

Comment: added the definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct human_t steve = {.name = "Steve", 
                          .title = "Mr.", 
                          .gender = male
                         };
```

Here `name` (and `title`) is initialized with the address of a *string literal*. String literals are not allocated from heap and in fact they are (usually) read-only. So string literals should always be assigned to `const char*` if you want to write more robust code.

---

So in the first snippet, `strcpy(steve.name, "AA");` will try to write to read-only memory and crashes. If you had made `steve.name` a const char, it would have produced a compiler error and you would have been safe.

---

Then 2nd snippet, `realloc(steve.name, strlen(new_name));` will try to resize a memory block which was not allocated with `malloc`. So you get a crash.

Also, this is not how you use `realloc` at all. You need to do it like this:

```
char *tmp = realloc(steve.name, strlen(new_name)+1);
if (!tmp) { perror("realloc error"); exit(1); }
strcpy(tmp, new_name);
steve.name = tmp;
```

---

To fix, store copy of the string:

```
struct human_t steve = {.name = strdup("Steve"), 
                          .title = strdup("Mr."), 
                          .gender = male
                         };
```

---

Here `strdup` is a POSIX function, but not standard C function, so you may need to define it yourself:

```
char *strdup(const char *src)
{
    char *dst = src ? malloc(strlen(src)+1) : NULL;
    if (dst) strcpy(dst, src);
    return dst;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this complete and concise reply. I suspected it had to do with things being allocated on the stack...

Comment: @gordon_freeman Since I'm not sure what you mean by "allocated on the stack" above, I'll say this: This code does not store any strings (the actual string data) in the stack. String literals are stored as part of the static data of the application, by default in the read-only part of it. In other words, they are loaded to memory directly as the application is loaded, and then you just have pointers to them.

Comment: indeed you're write, my wording was incorrect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In this declaration

```
struct human_t steve = {.name = "Steve", 
                          .title = "Mr.", 
                          .gender = male
                         };
```

you initialized the pointer `name` with the address of the first character of the string literal `"Steve"`.

Then in this statement

```
strcpy(steve.name, "AA");
```

you was trying to change the string literal.

Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

Instead you could just write

```
steve.name = "AA";
```

After that the pointer `name` will point to the string literal `"AA"`.

In this statement

```
realloc(steve.name, strlen(new_name));
```

you are trying to reallocate the memory occupied by a string literal that has static storage duration. But you may reallocate only memory that was previously allocated dynamically. Moreover in general you need to assign to a pointer the returned address of a call of `realloc`. Otherwise the address of the reallocated memory will be lost and you will have a memory leak.

Either declare the data member name as a character array as for example

```
struct human_t {
    char name[10[;
    char * title;
    sexe gender;
};
```

Or always allocate dynamically a memory to store there a string as for example

```
struct human_t steve = {.name = malloc( 10 ), 
                          .title = "Mr.", 
                          .gender = male
                         };

strcpy( steve.name, "Steve" );
```

The same problem exists with another data member `title`.

Comment: If intention is to store pointer to string literal in `title`, I would make it `const char*`.